# Accessing to a file and folder in Apache from Localhsot

Tags: apache, localhost

I want to create a virtual folder with a file in it in Apache, and to see that file from my browser : how can i fix it ?

the error i get when i try my local host in browser:
You don't have permission to access / on this server.

I tried:

1) created a folder in etc/apache2/sites-available

2) checking the default Apache settings which is not blocking my IP which is 192.168.1.5:

Comment: Suggest you look at the Apache documentation, specifically "DocumentRoot", "Directory" and "Alias" directives. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are trying to serve /yourfolder. Change the permission of the folder to give access right to others (755 for example) and add following to site conf you have created.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com:80
DocumentRoot /yourfolder

# Change according to your folder path
<Directory /yourfolder>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow From All
    Options -Indexes
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```